MoveIt Rviz ROS Iron - No planning library loaded
I am having trouble with MoveIt in ROS Iron.  I got through all the steps in the installation from  https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html, have cyclone_dds installed and a realtime kernel working, and started out having issues with MoveIt and my UR3e.  I backed off to try the demo in the MoveIt quickstart (which launches the G3 Kinova model) and am still having issues.
I've attached the entire launch's terminal output below.  When I run this, RViz shows the Kinova in candlestick position and MotionPlanning has the warning "PlanningScene" "Requesting initial scene failed".  It also, in the Context menu, has a bright red "NO PLANNING LIBRARY LOADED", and the handles for moving the robot in RViz are not visible.
When I run RViz with the UR3e, launching the MotionPlanning plugin out of moveit_ros_visualization crashes RViz entirely.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling MoveIt2, but nothing seems different.
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/kat/.ros/log/2024-06-12-12-21-39-056126-ceeo-ur3-ceres-6161
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [6164]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process started with pid [6166]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [6168]
[INFO] [move_group-4]: process started with pid [6170]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [6172]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [6174]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [6176]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [6178]
[static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1718209299.432238138] [static_transform_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-2] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[rviz2-1] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443646706] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443726118] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bracelet_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443737132] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment end_effector_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443745078] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forearm_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443752262] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment half_arm_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443759021] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment half_arm_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443765483] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443772408] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_finger_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443779153] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_finger_tip_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443785751] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_inner_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443792393] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443799081] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_finger_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443805688] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_finger_tip_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443812204] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_inner_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443818591] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443824832] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment shoulder_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443831198] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment spherical_wrist_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443837651] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment spherical_wrist_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718209299.443844052] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.455383050] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '/robot_description' topic for robot description.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.455439432] [controller_manager]: update rate is 1000 Hz
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.456666261] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.456983267] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457751898] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1718209299.457774831] [mock_generic_system]: Parameter 'fake_sensor_commands' has been deprecated from usage. Use'mock_sensor_commands' instead.
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1718209299.457806862] [mock_generic_system]: Parsing of optional initial interface values failed or uses a deprecated format. Add initial values for every state interface in the ros2_control.xacro. For example: 
[ros2_control_node-5] <state_interface name="velocity"> 
[ros2_control_node-5]   <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
[ros2_control_node-5] </state_interface>
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457817023] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457837062] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457846072] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1718209299.457854764] [mock_generic_system]: Parameter 'fake_sensor_commands' has been deprecated from usage. Use'mock_sensor_commands' instead.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457869033] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457913886] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457922384] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457928388] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457932087] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457935640] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457938682] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457944965] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.457948198] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.462708432] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1718209299.462745942] [controller_manager]: ResourceManager has already loaded an urdf file. Ignoring attempt to reload a robot description file.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.462959739] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00307107 seconds
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.463044350] [move_group.moveit.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.463065166] [move_group.moveit.moveit.core.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.543706042] [move_group.moveit.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.638201120] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.643573790] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'robotiq_gripper_controller'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209299.650564325] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209299.650637007] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1718209299.652156430] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.652653531] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.652713357] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1718209299.658086398] [spawner_robotiq_gripper_controller]: Loaded robotiq_gripper_controller
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1718209299.658104020] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.658588415] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'robotiq_gripper_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.658654467] [robotiq_gripper_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20Hz.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209299.662537452] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1718209299.663046407] [spawner_robotiq_gripper_controller]: Configured and activated robotiq_gripper_controller
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.747490518] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.747601835] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.747899517] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.748118763] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.748126231] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopping existing planning scene publisher.
[rviz2-1] [WARN] [1718209299.748160767] [rcl.logging_rosout]: Publisher already registered for provided node name. If this is due to multiple nodes with the same name then all logs for that logger name will go out over the existing publisher. As soon as any node with that name is destructed it will unregister the publisher, preventing any further logs for that name from being published on the rosout topic.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.748221253] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopped publishing maintained planning scene.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.748620917] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.748671698] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.749101966] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.749114565] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.749294185] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1718209299.749467795] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-4] [WARN] [1718209299.750240818] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1718209299.750255815] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[rviz2-1] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-1]          at line 321 in /opt/ros/iron/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209299.771538522] [rviz2.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00263316 seconds
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209299.771591995] [rviz2.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209299.771605651] [rviz2.moveit.core.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[move_group-4] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::ParameterTypeException'
[move_group-4]   what():  expected [string_array] got [string]
[move_group-4] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[move_group-4] #17   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[move_group-4] #16   Object "/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_move_group/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group", at 0x559cfca9b204, in _start
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.848530851] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1718209299.853213551] [joint_trajectory_controller]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to false. (The default behavior changed to false, and trajectories might get discarded.)
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1718209299.854145544] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Loaded joint_trajectory_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.854637984] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.854782794] [joint_trajectory_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.854813700] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.854826471] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1718209299.856125576] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1718209299.861120309] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Configured and activated joint_trajectory_controller
[move_group-4] #15   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7f3ecb504e3f]
[move_group-4] #14   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x7f3ecb504d8f]
[move_group-4] #13   Object "/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_move_group/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group", at 0x559cfca9a1c3, in main
[move_group-4] #12   Object "/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_planning/lib/libmoveit_cpp.so.2.9.0", at 0x7f3ecbe5e6a7, in moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::MoveItCpp(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> const&, moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::Options const&)
[move_group-4] #11   Object "/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_planning/lib/libmoveit_cpp.so.2.9.0", at 0x7f3ecbe5d5cb, in moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::loadPlanningPipelines(moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::PlanningPipelineOptions const&)
[move_group-4] #10   Object "/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_planning/lib/libmoveit_planning_pipeline_interfaces.so.2.9.0", at 0x7f3ecb28bfab, in moveit::planning_pipeline_interfaces::createPlanningPipelineMap(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::shared_ptr<moveit::core::RobotModel const> const&, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[move_group-4] #9    Object "/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_planning/lib/libmoveit_planning_pipeline.so.2.9.0", at 0x7f3ecb120fc5, in planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline::PlanningPipeline(std::shared_ptr<moveit::core::RobotModel const> const&, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[move_group-4] #8    Object "/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_planning/lib/libmoveit_planning_pipeline.so.2.9.0", at 0x7f3ecb16263d, in planning_pipeline_parameters::ParamListener::declare_params()
[move_group-4] #7    Object "/opt/ros/iron/lib/librclcpp.so", at 0x7f3ecba63869, in 
[move_group-4] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f3ecb7d24d7, in __cxa_throw
[move_group-4] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f3ecb7d2276, in std::terminate()
[move_group-4] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f3ecb7d220b, in 
[move_group-4] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f3ecb7c6b9d, in 
[move_group-4] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7f3ecb5037f2]
[move_group-4] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7f3ecb51d475]
[move_group-4] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[move_group-4]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[move_group-4]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7f3ecb5719fc]
[move_group-4] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 6170 1000)
[ERROR] [move_group-4]: process has died [pid 6170, exit code -6, cmd '/home/kat/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_move_group/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_15r250nz'].
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 6174]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 6178]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 6176]
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1718209303.000742744] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.019300538] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.086850162] [rviz2.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00215431 seconds
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.086899797] [rviz2.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.086913777] [rviz2.moveit.core.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.165418664] [rviz2.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.386775175] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.387802303] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.391395264] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.392753612] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.399773335] [interactive_marker_display_94781221546272]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.402683742] [rviz2.moveit.ros.robot_interaction]: No active joints or end effectors found for group 'gripper'. Make sure that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.403302487] [rviz2.moveit.ros.robot_interaction]: No active joints or end effectors found for group 'gripper'. Make sure that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.418686513] [interactive_marker_display_94781221546272]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209303.450372056] [interactive_marker_display_94781221546272]: Service response received for initialization
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209308.392539956] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209308.405357943] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209308.405512768] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: group gripper
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1718209308.405532760] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'gripper' in namespace ''


Update:  I never resolved this, but I was able to get moveit running by launching it and rviz as a separate thread, per these instructions: https://docs.ros.org/en/ros2_packages/rolling/api/ur_robot_driver/usage.html
(first launching the driver and then doing:
ros2 launch ur_moveit_config ur_moveit.launch.py ur_type:=ur3e launch_rviz:=true
